# SFMC: Unsubscribed customers still receiving commercial emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, gdpr

We have discovered that some unsubscribed customers are still receiving commercial emails when they shouldn't do as they have unsubscribed prior to the emails we're sending, some of them as early as 2020. We have opened up a ticket with Marketing Cloud but they haven't been able to identify why this is happening. Their status under All Subscribers is unsubscribed so this shouldn't happen. Has anyone else experienced this? Thank you.

Comment: Status is maintained by SubscriberKey.  I suspect you have duplicate SKs by email.

Comment: What Adam said. Sounds like a duplicates issue, which can be a larger sort of issue. A quick hotfix could be to enter the relevant emails onto an auto suppression configuration, which does the opposite. auto-suppression blocks by email, not subscriberkey. This does of course not address the root cause.